# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'. Nothing helpes

Tags: android

First, I want to say that I googled this problem already but nothing helped.
I have a project and a library. Project's dependenies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')        
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile ('org.mycompany.mylib:gmapslib:1.0.5') {
        transitive = false;
    }
```

And library's dependencies (org.mycompany.mylib:gmapslib):

```
dependencies {          
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

But still, when I'm trying to build the project I get this:

```
Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

Here is the result of gradlew app:dependencies

```
_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- ru.yandex:yandexmapkit:1.0.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.3.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
+--- org.mycompany.mylib:gmapslib:1.0.6
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-net:3.3
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 23.3.0 (*)
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
     +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.3.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
```

It's crazy, isn't it? What if I have google play services dependenices in, say, 3 libraries and also in the main project? What am I to do in this case? That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I think `org.mycompany.mylib:gmapslib:1.0.5` also contains `com.google.android.gms`, so try like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')        
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
   compile ('org.mycompany.mylib:gmapslib:1.0.5') {
       transitive = false
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Comment: I tried, still no luck. And yes. it contains com.google.android.gms, because the library has this dpendency compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Comment: @SergeyMaslov, have include any `jar` which has `com.google.android.gms` as dependencies?

Comment: It has! As I mentiond in the comment earlier, mylib depends on com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0

Comment: @SergeyMaslov and include this `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'` doesn't solve problem?

Comment: nice idea about the .jar, but, unfortunately, I don't have jars with google.android.gms dependencies

Comment: @RohitAria, exclufing group does not solve the problem

Comment: that didn't help either